# What percent of the time is unload or onunload called? And Why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, dom-events

I have heard in the past unload, or onunload, is not always called.  However, I would like to know how often it is not called.  What conditions lead to it not being called?  Is this different for Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing a while ago. I used two techniques:

```
$(window).unload( fn ); // jQuery method  

window.onbeforeunload = fn; // by Microsoft, but implemented in most browsers
```

You can view my test results here: http://vidasp.net/jQuery-unload.html
(To sum them up: `window.onbeforeunload` has complete support in all popular browsers except Opera)

Comment: How come you used onbeforeonload rather than onunload?

Comment: @Grea I actually cannot remember why I did that. But there must have been some valid reason. Maybe I figured that `onbeforeunload` has greater support than `onunload` so I just went with it...